# iPhone 6 viewcontroller unnecessary resetting

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, user-interface

I am fixing a quite old application written with objC & storyboard.

Code & storyboard do not have any sign of auto-layout or size classes & Images.xcassets is empty as well, It only have splash with 2x & Retina 4 and app icons,

All images are just put into a folder with 1x and 2x sizes.

But amazingly all screens resized automatically for both iPhone 6 and 6 plus.

Issue with current code is when any screen loads, it reset from left to right in bottom i.e. more likely toward bottom-right-corner of screen.

**I am just wondering about these two things**

- First: Why and how can this work without any assets for iPhone 6 & 6 plus
  (except Default / Splash)
- Second: Why each screen is resetting toward right corner in bottom, after its load?

Comment: can you share the picture with reseting? Hard to imagine. Without launch images everything works in scale mode.

Comment: @nyekimov I cant take picture because it happen so quick more likely a second or more you can see it but can't capture it, for more detail i can tell you, its kind of ZOOM whole window/view towards right corner in bottom and then it goes back to screen size. I will try to capture image or video for this.